# where to start if you lack basics?

Tags: soft-question, education

I've joined this forum for few weeks now and it amazes me that so many people are good at math. For me, I'm more of a history person rather than math person, so I hated math since I was young, not because math itself is bad, but because I thought math was not necessary in our daily lives and I wouldn't even use it when I grow up. Then after I joined this forum, I changed my mind and actually started to think that math is fun and it is the most essential part of our daily lives. I realized that everything is related to math, even history! Now, I want to start studying math but I lack kind of basics of math, and I don't know where to start from. I know basic algebras and just a bit of calculus. I'm afraid because since I'm already a grown up, my brain cannot follow the difficulties of math. Can you give me any tips on how to become good in math? Any personal story is appreciated.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your brain can certainly do it.  Math always looks harder than it really is.

Comment: @littleO yeah I hope so too.. sometimes when it takes 30-40 minutes to understand other people's answers, I feel like it takes a lot longer than it should be, and that's the moment I feel like my brain is aged (or simply I just lack enough knowledge to understand quickly) When that moment comes, I feel depressed and regret that I didn't study math hard enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you will have to judge where you are in the grand scheme of things. I'd say get yourself steady with algebra and calculus first, you could do some probability on the side as well if you want. These 3 things will give you a pretty good foundation to take maths further.

There's a book called Thomas Calculus its often recommended for people starting calculus it will definitely cover everything you could want to know and then some more. I think your best bet though depending on your level is to look at a mathematics department website at a university or college and see what their recommended texts are for their first year calculus and core algebra modules. Sometimes lecturers will upload their lecture notes as pdfs and you can download them (just google *module title* lecture notes). They are obviously course specific and only contain what the lecturer wants to teach however.

For calculus look at:
Functions - Domain, range, inverse, limits, continuity, derivatives.
Differentiation - Chain/product/quotient rules, derivatives of standard functions (exponential, sin, cos etc.) Logarithms, L'hopital's rule, curve sketching, local extrema and asymptotics.
Hyperbolic Functions
Integration - Definite/indefinite integrals, Anti-derivatives, FTOC. Integration by parts, Integration by substitution.
Parametric curves.
Ordinary differential equations. 
Taylor series.
Fourier series
Functions of 2 variables.
Partial differentiation.
Double integrals.

Algebra:
Basic set theory
The number sets $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ etc
proof by induction/contradiction/contrapositive [Understanding proofs is fundamental], iff, necessary, sufficient
injections, surjections, bijections and function inverses 
vectors
dot/cross products
complex numbers
FTOAlgebra
Matrix algebra up to 3x3 (including finding inverse)
reducing matrices to echelon form 
systems of linear equations
linear independence
eigenvalues and eigenvectors
matrices that represent rotations and reflections in 2D/3D
Basic groups

Once you have the foundations down I'd recommend studying some probability, statistics, linear algebra and some classical mechanics. If you are really set on taking maths far then you should also study real analysis. After this is where everything starts to get awesome (if it already wasn't). You can really decide what kind of mathematics you want to do, there's number theory, differential equations, complex analysis, more probability/statistics, multivariable/vector calculus, fluid dynamics, (groups rings and fields), quantum mechanics, special/general relativity, programming languages, the list is pretty much endless. Personally i'm all about the quantum mechanics, a lot of QFT recently.

One tip I'd say is never give up. Maths can seem very hard at times but when you finally understand a concept that can't be taken away from you. You'll look back at things you studied 6 months prior and it will all seem so much easier than what you are doing now. It just takes a bit of practice and some dedication to stick at it. If you are ever stuck you can just ask us as well ^^. 
Good luck and have fun!

Ill add some fundamentals to get you started later when im on my pc.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! hopefully I will become better at math just  like people in this forum

Comment: Im sure you will, dont worry about being slow as well. Its a sure sign that your attempting to understand everything, which is great. At the moment some notes im reading take me on average about an hour per page to read because im trying to understand every equation fully. You'll get quicker with time as well. Like everything you get better with practice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm 51 years old. I did some math in high school, but hadn't done anything but basic algebra (plus a little statistics) for 30 years.

4.5 years ago, at 47, I decided to go to college, and had to start back at nearly the beginning (Algebra II). I'm about to graduate with a minor in mathematics, and I'll be going to graduate school to get a master's in economics and applied mathematics.

I'll never be Euler, but if you keep an open mind and don't convince yourself you can't do it, you can do math.

I would start taking classes at your local community/junior college. The discipline and guidance will help a lot. I don't know where you're at, but the CC I went to has Alg. II, Trig, Calc I, II, and III, differential equations and linear algebra, which is 5/6 of the way to a math minor.

Comment: thanks for sharing your story, I'm just wondering if you had any difficulties following the lectures since you only knew basic algebra and how you overcome those difficulties? Did you study other than class material?

Comment: Well, Algebra II just requires basic algebra, and everything builds from there. My secret was that I attended *every* class and did *all* the homework.